# Continuous function $0$ on one closed set and $1$ on the other

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functions, alternative-proof

Looking for a better approach of the following question if possible.

Question: Let $A$ and $B$ be disjoint nonempty closed sets in a metric spaces $X$, and define $f(p)=\frac{\rho_A(p)}{\rho_A(p)+\rho_B(p)}$, $p\in X$ ($\rho $ is distance between point and set). Show that $f$ is continuous function on X whose range lies in $[0,1]$, $f(p)=0$ on $A$ and $f(p)=1$ on B.

Thought: Only continuity of $f$ is the non-trivial, we try to prove for given $\epsilon>0$ exist $\delta>0$ $d(p,q)<\delta$ implies $|f(p)-f(q)|<\epsilon$. To achieve the goal, try to find a small enough $\delta$ and points in set $A$ and $B$ that "estimate" distance (e.g. $d(a\in A,p)-\rho_A(p)$ small enough). However the inequality looks quite messy when I try to write down the rigorous proof.

Comment: Show that $\rho_C$ is continuous for all non-empty $C\subset X$. Then the continuity of $f$ follows by standard theorems.

Comment: When you prove that $\rho_A(p)+\rho_B(p)\ne0$ for all $p$, you're done, because $\rho_A$ is a continuous function.

Comment: @ Daniel Fischer and egreg, thanks. Looks like I miss something simple...

Comment: Try showing that $\lvert \rho_C(x) - \rho_C(y)\rvert \leqslant d(x,y)$.